# Array, remove/replace key index

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code:

```
   $path = "./wp-content/uploads/webvideos/";
$webdir = site_url()."/wp-content/uploads/webvideos/";
$post_title = html_entity_decode(get_the_title());


$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS));
$files = array();
$notAllowedExtension = array('jpg', 'mp3', 'vtr', 'html', 'htm' );

foreach($iterator as $file){



if(!in_array($file->getExtension(), $notAllowedExtension) && !$file->isDir())
    $files[] = $file->getFilename();

}


ksort($files);

foreach($files as $value){
    Echo $value . "<br>";
}



if( $autoplay > count( $files ) ) $autoplay = 1;

if( $autoplay > 0 ) $autoplay = $autoplay -1;

foreach($files as $file => $date){
if(  $i==$autoplay ) $file_main = $file;
$output .= "" . PHP_EOL .
 "<tr>
     <td><a href=\"javascript:loadVideo('$webdir$file.mp4')\"> $file - (Click Me)</a>
</td>
    <td>NA</td>     

  </tr>"
. PHP_EOL;
$i++;
}
```

I have added more of the code. Now I have an issue because the echo works but not the rest of the code.

However, the output is:

```
[1350528689] => V001 - Test Video.mp4
[1350568321] => V001-Test-Video.mp4
[1430061765] => V001-My-First-Video.mp4
```

But I need it to be like this:

```
V001 - Test Video.mp4
V001-Test-Video.mp4
V001-My-First-Video.mp4
```

I have spent hours looking for a solution, but not joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$title=$files[$file]; 
 if( $i==$autoplay ) $file_main = $file; 
 $output .= "" . PHP_EOL . 
 "<tr> 
 <td><a href=\"javascript:loadVideo('$webdir$file.mp4')\"> $file - $title(Click Me)</a>
```

The final answer is this.

Comment: It does work outputting with echo however the rest of the $files as the key index, not the value.

Comment: Can you explain better doing some examples? Thanks  P.S. I have based my answer on your output

Comment: Hi CiroRa, of course. Your code echos the value of the array, this is perfect. However, if you look at my code above. It does not output the value, but rather the key. 

For example `<td><a href=\"javascript:loadVideo('$webdir$file.mp4')\"> $file - (Click Me)</a>`

$file should be:`V001 - Test Video.mp4` but it comes up as `[1350528689]`

Comment: Then I use you code, I echo the value. However, throughout the rest of the code it outputs as the Array keys. I am not sure why.

Comment: Please echo the $file variables. In the meanwhile, If I understood correctly, try to echo in that foreach $files[$value][1] and see what happen

Comment: `foreach($files as $value){
    Echo $value . "<br>\n";
}` Nothing came up

Comment: The code you are suggesting is exactly where, sorry.

Comment: print_r($files) to see the structure of your $files so I can reach directly the title of your video. Please note that you have missed a "s" in $file

Comment: WIth the `s`, it come up with the perfect list. This is what I want however it does not seems to work in the rest of the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114484/discussion-between-arthor-and-cirora).

Comment: Please confirm the answer to show the post as solved

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if(!in_array($file->getExtension(), $notAllowedExtension) && !$file->isDir())
    $files[] = $file->getFilename();

}
```

Edit: but this will not remove the key. It will make it 0, 1, 2 etc.
I'm quite sure you can't have an array without keys.

Or is the question how to print the files without the keys?

Edit ok..  so you need to print them without keys.

```
foreach($files as $value){
    Echo $value . "<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: Not quite, it comes up like so: `[0] => V001 - Test Video.mp4
[1] => V001-Test-Video.mp4
[1] => V001-My-First-Video.mp4` I also recall trying this as well.

Comment: Print_r and var_dump are used to see how an array is set up. What you need is to echo the array values

Comment: @Arthor got it working? The last part is the only thing you need. The foreach... and it should replace your code: `echo "<pre>" . print_r($files, true) . "</pre>";`

Comment: I have updated the code, the echo work perfectly HOWEVER, the rest of the code only show the key. How would I get the output of the echo to be the same through the rest of the code. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need the keyvalue as it was. Reset the part where $file[`this part`]= to what it was and maybe it works. It should. But I can't guarrantee it.

Comment: Sorry, I do not yet you on your last comment, thanks

Comment: Effectively I would like to use the values, not the keys. The echo prints they out perfectly. I would have never thought that this would be a daunting task.